Instances moving along path want to duplicate and create an echo like effect
I have this set up which I like, it simply lets me slide the object along the curve. I was interested in knowing if it's possible to duplicate then offset the effect plus scaling down or up the duplicates that can create a trail or echo like effect. I tried the duplicate element node but couldn't figure out how to get the duplicates to stay on the curve and trail behind. Still very new to geo nodes


